# Comparator issue in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I have a `Map<String, AtomicInteger> map` in Java that I am trying to sort according to value (and then print). I have found a way that seems quick enough which is to first make an array `Object[] a = map.entrySet().toArray();`
And then I try to sort it like so

```
Arrays.sort(a, Comparator.comparingInt((Object entry) -> entry.getValue().get()))
```

Or like so:

```
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger>) o2).getValue()
                    .compareTo(((Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger>) o1).getValue());
        }
    })
```

Unfortunately both these syntaxes are slightly wrong. In the first case it does not recognise the function getValue(), in the seconds it's compareTo that doesn't work. Can someone suggest corrections to the syntax to make it work?

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings.  This will give you a useful warning which explains, correctly, that `new Comparator` without a generic type is a raw type.  And another warning that `(Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger>)` is an unsafe cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why extract into an array? Why not just use `sorted()` on the entries directly?

For example:

```
private static List<Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger>> sortedEntries(
        Map<String, AtomicInteger> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getValue().get()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Is it faster/more orderly?

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
Arrays.sort(a, Comparator.comparingInt((Object entry) -> entry.getValue().get()))
```

You are declaring the parameter to be `Object`. But it isn't. It is an Entry. And surprise, the class `Object` doesn't have methods such as `getValue()`!

And you shouldn't need to give the type in the first place:

```
Arrays.sort(a, Comparator.comparingInt(e -> entry.getValue().get()))
```

should do.

And yes, I missed that: the first problem is that `a` should be an array of `Entry` values not a `Object[]`.

Besides: use names that mean something. `a` means like ... nothing.

Comment: I agree with almost everything, but it would work if the input array was of `Entry` class, but it's `Object` -> getValue() is undefined

Comment: @HBo uups. I overlooked that. I added that part to my answer. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: trouble is, the `toArray` method returns an array of... objects... so it requires an intermediate array to do the job.